# Неглавная форма приложения поверх всех форм только этого приложения

Tags: forms, delphi, форма

Есть приложение с кучей форм. И нужно показывать сообщение в форме, которая должна быть только поверх всех форм этого приложения, не вылезая на передний план других приложений, так сказать... Надеюсь выразился более-менее понятно. Буду благодарен за даже за правильно сформулированный запрос для гугла!

Comment: Для гугла 1. `Form1.ShowModal;`
2. `Form1.FormStyle := fsStayOnTop;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Наверное, есть смысл делать это окно поверх всех окон системы. Но, при этом, пошаманить в `Application.OnActivate` и `Application.OnDeactivate`. Эти события отрабатывает при получении и утере фокуса на уровне всего приложения.